# How to implement region-specific app in Laravel Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 6.

I am building an app that has Files (not a file stored on your desktop or storage). I have a File model, FileController controller and Files in the `DB` with `id, user_id` (as it belongs to a user) and data (which is a JSON column).

For my app, a File can have different fields, based on jurisdiction, that need to be captured (via forms on the blade templates) and managed via the controller (primarily via show, edit, update).

It is likely that I have many jurisdictions (imagine country, state and maybe city) versions of Files, with their respective fields that need to be captured, displayed, modified, etc.

In many of these Files, especially if its in the same country, there are fields (columns/keys) that are repeated.

Currently, I have one Controller, and when it comes to editing a File, showing a File or updating a File, I am starting to have logic that detects the country or state and modifying the logic or view.

Initially I thought I would do something like this

```
File - model
FileController - root controller
- @edit calls FileControllers/country/state/FileController@edit.php
- @show calls FileControllers/country/state/FileController@show.php
- @update will reference FileControllers/country/state/FileController@update
Files.view.blade - root view for Show
Files.edit.blade - root view for Edit
```

but I have a feeling this is going to get out of hand really quickly, especially if certain File records have similar fields, views, data types that I will capture. There aren't any that are consist across the various different jurisdictions, which is why I opted for a JSON store in the mysql database.

What are some ways to dynamically manage this sort of setup with relative ease of maintainability, in the long run? I am a beginner-ish to novice-ish developer.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve decided for the purposes of moving my project forward to setup region specific controllers and views and to use Web.php to handle the routes such as

So I’ll be running:

```
php artisan make:controller /us/ny/FileController

Route::get(‘file/edit,’$country.’/‘.$state.’/FileController@edit’);
```

With some code to detect that those exist.

I’m still open to feedback and advice as I’m happy to refactor with a better way to manage it, especially with any reusable parts.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to log another answer in the event another developer is going down this path and looking for an answer.

Not sure if this is the best way but I've decided to invoke the method from within a root controller.

So

```
Route::patch('/file','FileController@update');
```

Within FileController, the update() method has

```
app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\\'.$country.'\FileController@Update')
```

I've read this isn't the best way to do it, but have not found specific alternatives.